# Splitting vector at zero-elements

Tags: r, vector, split, max, intervals

I've got a numeric vector in R with intervals of increasing integers separated by arbitrary numbers of zeros. Example given by:

```
x = c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0)
```

I would like to find the `max()`/ last element in each of these increasing intervals separated by zeros.
For the given example, this would be:

```
result
[1] 3 2
```

Doing this by looping over the elements of `x` does the job but seems rather primitive (code given below).  As I'm new to R and couldn't figure out a smarter way possibly using `cut()` and `split()` I'd appreciate advice on a more elegant solution. Thanks!

```
x  <-  c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0)
interval_max <- 0
interval_counter <- 0
result <- 0
in_interval = FALSE


for (n in 1:10){
  if (x[n]>0){
    if (in_interval){
      result[interval_counter] <- x[n]
    }
    else {
      interval_counter <-  interval_counter + 1
      result[interval_counter] <- x[n]
      in_interval <- TRUE
    }
  }
  else {
    in_interval <- FALSE
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want are the values then:

```
x <- c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0)
x[diff(x) < 0]
# [1] 3 2
```

Course this assumes the values are always increasing and then resetting to zero.